# Core Data array

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am using the code below to fetch the objects in an array. In my program, I have an array displayed in a tableview and when a cell is tapped, it leads to another array displayed in a tableview. The user can add cells in both of these tableviews. What is happening is that when I create new rows in my second tableview, go back, and tap the same cell that got me there, I notice that the objects I created are not there (they were reassigned to another cell). I believe that the problem lies in the line: `routines = results`. What I think is happening, is that when I tap back in my second view, the line `routines = results` is called again, and because `results` is by nature unordered, it messes up the order of my previously established `routines` array.

```
var routines = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Routine")

    var error: NSError?

    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as! [NSManagedObject]?

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        routines = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using NSFetchedResultsController when fetching NSManagedObjects from CoreData. Other than that, you could assign a NSSortDescriptor to the NSFetchRequest to sort your NSManagedObjects according to some key.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment from Jonathan.  You are just making work for yourself holding onto everything in arrays.  Use the tools that are designed to work with both Core Data and UITableView controllers and you will have a much easier (and more maintainable) time.